# Access Denied when using Get-FileHash in Invoke-Command -Session/ComputerName

Tags: powershell

When I run this code it returns Access Denied:

```
$file = '\\share\file'
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName servername -Credential domain\user
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock  {Get-FileHash -LiteralPath $args[0]} -ArgumentList $file
```

The account has the correct permissions. When running Get-FileHash outside of Invoke-Command on the same file, locally it works as expected. I've also tried grabbing the file from Get-ChildItem and piping to Get-FileHash with the same result.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: does the account used have permission to access that share _without elevation_? my understanding is that the account will not be elevated on the remote system ... take a look at the `double hop problem` for a far better description & some of the various workarounds.

Comment: Yes, the account has full control without elevation. I tested several accounts to verify. I'll read up on "double hop problem".

Comment: I enabled Enable-WSManCredSSP between the servers and no change. I followed this article. https://www.travisgan.com/2014/03/enable-powershell-double-hop-remoting.html

Comment: Running Get-FileHash in Invoke-Command against a local file of the target server works as expected. It does seem to be a "double hop" type of issue.

Comment: Looks like by design not allowed.https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/da98e33a-9f4f-41c6-a437-acfea10ee405/invokecommand-getchilditem-share-unauthorizedaccessexception?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: This is a great work around https://blog.ipswitch.com/the-infamous-double-hop-problem-in-powershell

Comment: yep .... the double hop problem has been causing hair loss amung PoSh folks for a while now. glad that you found a usable workaround! [*grin*]

Comment: Please do not edit tags into the subject of your question.